# How to set horizontal scrollbar for TableView?

Tags: java, javafx, resize, tableview, scrollbar

I have an issue with my tableView. My tableview has two columns and rows inside second one are file paths. So i would like to implement scrollbar to see whole path by scrolling, because tableView size is fixed.

I've added *setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);*
It shows scrollbar, but i cant move it.

Is there any functional solution?

[image]

Comment: The scrollbar isn't movable because the entire `TableView` is already showing. Increase the width of your second `TableColumn` (either in the code or by dragging it to the right within the UI) and the scrollbar will reflect the new width of the `TableView`. The `TableColumn` class does not automatically resize to the widest element in the data; at least not by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it isn't possible to upload an image into a comment I'm posting one in an answer. I just want to make sure you knew what I meant in my comment. If you did and/or this doesn't help you, let me know and I'll delete this answer.

This is what I meant by increasing the column width via the UI. As shown in the GIF, I did have to scroll a little to the right before I was able to resize the second column. This is probably because there are like 1 or 2 pixels "off screen" when the table is first rendered.

[image]

Here is the code I used to create this example (Java 10):

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        var table = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Person("John", "SomeGuyWithAReallyObnoxiouslyLongLastName"),
                new Person("Jane", "Smith")
        ));

        var firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(v -> v.getValue().firstNameProperty());

        var lastNameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(v -> v.getValue().lastNameProperty());

        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        primaryStage.setOnShown(we -> {
            we.consume();
            firstNameCol.setPrefWidth(table.getWidth() / 2.0);
            lastNameCol.setPrefWidth(table.getWidth() / 2.0);
        });

        var root = new StackPane(table);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(30.0));
        var scene = new Scene(root, 560.0, 360.0);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("People");
        // primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName");
        public final void setFirstName(String name) { firstName.set(name); }
        public final String getFirstName() { return firstName.get(); }
        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() { return firstName; }

        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName");
        public final void setLastName(String name) { lastName.set(name); }
        public final String getLastName() { return lastName.get(); }
        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() { return lastName; }

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setLastName(lastName);
        }

    }

}
```